# How does a pointer to a vector work?

Tags: c++

If I have the following:

```
vector<int> v(4,0);
vector<int>* p = &v;
int element = p[0];
```

Will element be the same value as `v[0]`?  I'm getting confused here about the `[]` operator.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `p->at(0)`...? (Confused by current answer.)

Comment: @muntoo yes you could do it that way, and this question is misleading because it presents the above code as if it's valid, when it's not and won't compile.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: no.

What you have is not even valid C++. `p[0]` is the same as `*p`, which is of type `vector<int>` and thus not convertible to `int`.

The `[]`-notation merely suggests that you think of `p` as  an *array* of vectors, and you are accessing the array's first element, which is `v`. More generally, for any pointer `p`, the notation `p[k]` is identical to `*(p + k)` (in fact to a fault, as you can say `a[5]` and `5[a]` interchangeably).

So if you really wanted to, you could write `p[0][i]` for the `i`th element of the vector, though it is more customary to just write `(*p)[i]` (parentheses needed for the correct precedence).

---

<sub>When I first skimmed over the question, I thought you might be looking for some clever hack and wanted to know whether `**(int**)(p)` was equal to `v[0]`. That is indeed plausible, as the first element of the vector's data structure is often the pointer to the vector's internal buffer. Don't use this at home.</sub>

Answer (score 6):

For any pointer `p`, `p[0]` is the same as `*p`. (More generally, `p[i]` is a special notation for `*(p+i)`. Fun fact: you can also write `i[p]`, because `*(p+i) == *(i+p)`. C and C++ are weird like that.) So in your case, where `p` is a pointer to `v`, you're essentially writing `int element = v;`. It won't work, because the right-hand-side is a vector.

Answer (score 4):

No, **p** it's a pointer to the vector, not the content! If you try to compile, you get something like

```
error: cannot convert ‘std::vector<int>’ to ‘int’ in initialization
```

from your compiler. Use `(*p)[0]` to get the value.